# Is it normal that the test ads in the Emulator are loaded so much slower that in a real device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob

I am developing my app and I have seen that the test admob ads in the Emulator are loaded like in 4 or 5 minutes after the app is opened (I have logged them when they were loaded). Otherwise, when I play my app in a real device, the test ads are shown inmediately as they are loaded at the first time and I don´t know why in all the devices of the Emulator, the test ads are loaded so much solower. The internet connection is fine, so I don´t understand this huge difference of ad load time. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal, usually test ads is loaded immediately on emulator.

One time this happened to me and then I remembered that I slowed down the emulator to test my app on bad connections. make sure you did not slow down your emulator manually.

Comment: I have made an inetrnet connection speed test on the emulator and it is almost the same as in my real devices, I don't know what is happening then..

Comment: I solved it updating the emulator finally...